# VmWare Host connection keeps on breaking

Tags: vmware-esxi, connection

I have installed VMware ESXi 5.1 and configured the static IP. When I try to connect to the host using the vSphere Client it logs in sucessfully. But after that when I try to access any thing I get following error

```
Call "PropertyCollector.CreateFilter" for object "ha-property-collector" on ESXi "192.168.25.52" failed.
```

and then the connection breaks. After that the connection to the server breaks. Any help on how I can fix this. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: what's between your client and the host - is there any form of router or firewall?

Comment: Both the machines are in the local network and there is no firewall between those two machines